# Save settings with custom property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, properties, application-settings

I have a setting which I have set to a custom property 
`DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode`. I assume this is an ENUM if that has anything to do with it all.

[image]

I have a method in my code which will get and set the property like this:

```
public DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode COLUMN_SIZE_MODE
{
   get { return Properties.Settings.Default.COLUMN_SIZE_MODE; }
   set { Properties.Settings.Default.COLUMN_SIZE_MODE = value; }
}
```

Now, the setting is controlled by a comboBox with all the alternatives that `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode` contains, and it's ok reading from it. However, I don't know how to save the selected value to the setting variable.

When I press the "save" button the value chosen in the comboBox should be saved to the settings variable. With other settings, which are just strings, I can just do like this:

```
DEFAULT_DATABASE = defaultDatabaseComboBox.Text;
```

But as I have set the other setting to a non-text property I am unable to use the .Text method to point to the value in the comboBox like this:

```
COLUMN_SIZE_MODE = columnSizeModeSetting.Text;
```

What can I do to save the text in my comboBox to the setting with a custom property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. I don't really understand it yet but here it is.

To save a setting from a comboBox, which contains a text, to a setting which is a custom enum property I did this:

```
COLUMN_SIZE_MODE = (DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)Enum.Parse( typeof(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode), columnSizeModeSetting.Text);
```

It seem to be a kind of conversion, but why I need to write like this I don't really understand yet.

Comment: This will bite you, once you decide you maybe want to use a descriptive text in your ComboBox instead of the enum value. Take a look at my answer, it also answers how you actually save the settings, so they're stored on your computer.

Comment: @BoredomOverload i actually have a save button doing the save settings function so that's already fine. But I will reflect and test upon your solution if that works better for me!